# How to make sure two paths don't refer to the same folder in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

On Windows, paths are case-insensitive, and on Linux they are case sensitive.

I have a file server that serves files, and that's fine, since it will serve based on the operating system in use. But I keep track of certain paths (all folder paths with a specific file inside), and load a new instance of a class for each of these paths. But my problem is that if someone is using an OS that is case-insensitive, it will load two instances for the same path, which is a no no. And yet I don't want to just compare on toLowerCase() because they could be on a case sensitive file system.

Is there a way to use the folder Stat info to check whether I have the same folder? Or some other way?

Comment: How about using a strategy that returns a reference to an existing class or a new one if class wasn't created yet for case insensitive file system? For the case-sensitive filesystem, you can always create a new class.

Comment: You only have two choices here: 1) Refuse to support names that differ only in case by not allowing that situation to exist in the first place and then you can do all comparisons with lowercase, 2) Detect whether the OS is case sensitive or not and do all comparisons in lowercase only for case-insensitive file systems.  Pick one.  You could do a case sensitivity test once at server startup to know.

Comment: As far as I know, nodejs does not offer some universal file ID that you could compare between two open files to see if they are the same.  You could open the first file for exclusive access and a subsequent attemp to open the same file would fail with an appropriate error to indicate it was already in use.

Comment: Using inodes from stats will have been convenient, however there is a issue with it being inconsistent on Windows. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12115

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fs.stat` to get https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

> For a regular file util.inspect(stats) would return a string very similar to this:

```
Stats {
dev: 2114,
ino: 48064969,
mode: 33188,
nlink: 1,
uid: 85,
gid: 100,
rdev: 0,
size: 527,
blksize: 4096,
blocks: 8,
atimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
mtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
ctimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
birthtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
atime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
mtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
ctime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
birthtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT }
```

I believe `ino` is your inode number, which *should* be unique for the disk partition you are talking about. If the path indicates partition, then for a particular path you should be good. I think this could be interesting if you want to deal with symlinks and other filesystem goodies.